# Visual Studio 2017 cannot open existing file

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2017

So I have a vcxproj file. Somewhere in there, there's this:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <ClCompile Include="CMakeCCompilerId.c" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Besides the vcxproj file, this referenced file exists. If I open the project in Visual Studio, it cannot compile with these error messages:

> Error (active)    E1696   cannot open source file "D:\PATH-TO-MY-PROJECT\CMAKECCOMPILERID.C"  CompilerIdC     0
>   Error C1083   Cannot open source file: 'CMakeCCompilerId.c': No such file or directory    CompilerIdC D:\Path-to-my-project\c1    1

If I open the project in the solution explorer, it shows the file with a red minus symbol. However, when I double-click it, an editor opens with the file's contents. So Visual Studio is just lying about how the file doesn't exist; it can even open it. However, *even after opening* the file in the explorer, when I try to compile it, I get the same error message.

How can I fix this?

(Background: This is actually a CMake-generated project that figures out the C compiler version. CMake cannot generate my solution because it fails to compile this project. I have another CMake project on the same machine which is able to figure out the correct C compiler using this very same project and I completely fail to figure out why one is working and the other one isn't.)

Comment: Did you make any progress with this problem? I have the same problem, and have no idea how to fix it. I updated Visual Studio and cmake, but it did not help. Other people have the same problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54155471/cmake-error-cannot-open-source-file-cmakeccompilerid-c

Comment: @Rémi I checked out the project to a different folder on a different hard drive and it worked there. However, there is no real indicator about what the problem was – I have other projects on both hard drives that work and I renamed the failing project's folder and it still didn't work before I checked it out to the other drive.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue plus Intellisense not working, both with VS 2019 and VS Code.

Deleting the .vs and .vscode folders did not solve the problem.

Cloning the repository in another folder worked for me both with VS Code and VS 2019. However, I won't consider that a definitive solution.